# wso2 manager - com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-stratos

I've downloaded WSO2 Stratos 1.5.2 platform.
I'm trying to start wso2stratos-manager-1.5.2, but it doesn't find the mysql jdbc driver

> [2012-08-08 16:31:15,201] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil} - Database Error -
>   Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver
>   class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

Answer (score 10):

I believe you're trying to use a mysql database as the backend database of the user management repository. Did you put the MySQL JDBC driver to MANAGER_HOME/repository/components/lib directory?

Regards,
Prabath

Comment: there's already mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar in MANAGER_HOME/repository/components/lib.
FYI, I managed to start the Identity Server successfully.

Comment: Can you please check whether there's any spaces (before/after) in the driver class name specified in "user-mgt.xml"?

Comment: There's no blank space.
Notice that I didn't have to add the driver jar myself, it was already embedded in the stratos package.

Comment: As Rob Church says in below comment: "The target directory has changed for Enterprise Integrator. You should place the driver in <EI_HOME>/lib directory."

Answer (score 8):

We do not ship the mysql-connector jar with our packs due to license issues. Therefore you need to copy the jar to repository/components/lib folder as mentioned in Prabath's reply.

Regards,
Amila.

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar is in MANAGER_HOME/repository/components/lib, so you do ship the mysql driver in stratos package.

Comment: mine didn't have the jar

Comment: I cannot recall about what @guillaume has mentioned since it is about an old product. But we cannot ship the driver due to the license mismatches I have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others but adding specific details.

When configuring the Datasource Driver in many of the WSO2 products you need to specify the class name of the JDBC driver to use.

Make sure to copy the JDBC driver relevant to the database engine to the /repository/components/lib/ directory.

For example, if you are using MySQL, specify com.mysql.jdbc.Driver as the driver and copy mysql-connector-java-5.XX-bin.jar file to this directory.

If you do not copy the driver to this directory when you create the datasource, you will get an exception similar to Cannot load JDBC driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

Comment: The target directory has changed for Enterprise Integrator. You should place the driver in <EI_HOME>/lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

Driver name is "**com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**".
JAR file (mysql-connector-java-x.xx.xx.jar) must be present in MANAGER_HOME/repository/components/lib

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding the mysql jar file at the directory

```
C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\6.1.0\repository\components\lib
```

You can download jar by the following link:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.20

After that you should restart the WSO2 server